# Users need to see files in Google Drive Account with Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I would like to do this:

I have an account ADMIN in Google Drive with a lot of files.
Some users will access the page of my app and they will need to see these files.

Is it possible users can see the files without login or any kind of authentication?

I'm confused about this because every content that i searched, talk about `access_token` and `permission` for the users.

Thanks everyone, sorry about my english.

Comment: look here [google-drive-ruby](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the google doesn't support this code anymore.